# pyqt UI File - set class property

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I've a .qss file with my styles.
That I load it into my application like this:

```
with open(_assets_folder + _css_file) as fh:
    main_view.setStyleSheet(fh.read())
```

And I've my view in a .ui file that I load into my application like this:

```
uic.loadUi(self._views_folder + ui_file, self)
```

And I'm able to apply classes from my .qss to my top_label1 like this (and it works):

```
self.top_label1.setProperty('class', 'top')
```

top class is in my .qss file:

```
.top {
    color: black;
    font-size: 82px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
    qproperty-alignment: 'AlignVCenter | AlignCenter';
}
```

and my label is in my .ui file:

```
    <widget class="QLabel" name="top_label1">
     <property name="sizePolicy">
      <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
       <horstretch>0</horstretch>
       <verstretch>0</verstretch>
      </sizepolicy>
     </property>
     <property name="minimumSize">
      <size>
       <width>330</width>
       <height>120</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <property name="baseSize">
      <size>
       <width>330</width>
       <height>120</height>
      </size>
     </property>
    </widget>
```

Is it possible to make set the class directly in the .ui file?
Is there any option to do it the QT Design?

I've tried to add (manually) the following but with no success:

```
     <property name="class">
      <string>top</string>
     </property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add "[dynamic properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html#dynamic-properties)" from the Property Editor of Designer:

[image]

Add a string property named "class" and set the name value accordingly.

Note that, while it's fine to use the dot-class selector (assuming that a string property named "class" is set), you can also use custom property names and use the square bracket selectors; for example, in the case above you can also use the following stylesheet:

```
QWidget[class="top"] {
    color: black;
    font-size: 82px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
    qproperty-alignment: 'AlignVCenter | AlignCenter';
}
```

Note that property values are always strings in stylesheets, so they *must* be enclosed in quotes, and boolean values *must* be lower case.
For example, if you add a boolean dynamic property named "bigFont", the stylesheet would be like this:

```
QWidget[bigFont="true"] {
    font-size: 82px;
}
```